# Django - rest framework errors when python runserver

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, terminal, django-rest-framework

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/WillRedington/Desktop/Django Projects/propadev/propvocab/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rest_framework import routers
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rest_framework import views
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from rest_framework.compat import HttpResponseBase, View
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.utils.six.moves.urllib import parse as urlparse
ImportError: No module named urllib
```

The server error message:  [17/Dec/2014 16:26:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59

This is checking if python returns the modules:

```
>>> import django.utils.six.moves
>>> import django.utils.six.moves.urllib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib
>>>
```

My current python version is 2.7.2, Django is 1.5.1, rest framework is in 2.7 site-package.
I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Django several times and get the same error.
This is running on Mac OS X 10.9.5, please help me, I've been at this for 5 hours.

Comment: `pip install -U six` it sounds like your version is out of date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems like a dependency error. Maybe you downgraded your django, or randomly installed the rest framework package without controlling the dependencies.

django.utils.six.moves.urllib doesnt exist in django==1.5.1 yet. You can try to upgrade django to 1.5.7 for example. Then this import will work. Other things might still be broken though, I can´t tell from here. If you post the output of pip freeze here, it may be easier to help.

You aren´t working in a virtual environment, which is dangerous for dependencies. Best is to make a virtualenv, then install your packages with pip, taking care of dependencies. 
Then run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and use that file in the future like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and edit the file accordingly if you install, update or remove packages.

Something that might be of interest is this: it generally never works to uninstall and reinstall the same package *several times*; if it doesn´t work once, it won´t work the second time either.

Comment: I had a similar problem and upgrading Django to 1.5.7 worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned before my response wasn't really an answer.  I solved this error and potentially many more by installing a python virtual environment.  To do this run the following

`sudo pip install virtualenv`

Then create a new folder for your virtual environments.  cd into the created folder.

```
cd myvirtualenv
```

Then create a new virtual environment by running the following:

```
virtualenv venv
```

To run the virtual env:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

This makes a seperate environment with it's own site packages, which is essential for any python developer, especially when working on multiple projects.

Source:  http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: You should use this, it makes using virtualenvs a breeze: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/